# Typescript use of Recursive Type Aliases

Tags: typescript

I have some code where I want to try to remove the use of:

```
let result: any;
```

result can be a large JSON returned from a REST api call.
and replace it with a recursive type alias
So I have this:

```
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Array<Json> | { [key: string]: Json };
```

As soon as I do that my code then complains with this:

```
if (result.reasonCode != "8700" && result.reasonCode != "8207") {
.
.}
```

for reasonCode not being defined.
So I then tried adding this - not sure of this is correct or not. It was just my attempt to get around the initial error. I was hoping to not have to use an interface. I am using TypeScript V5.

```
interface JsonArray extends Array<Json> {
  reasonCode: string;
  message: string;
}
```

then I changed result to then be:

```
let result: JsonArray;
```

now I do not get any compile errors for result.reasonCode.
but I now get another error

when I do:

```
if (result === "error" {
.
.}
```

with the error that
**This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'JsonArray' and 'string' have no overlap**

to get around that, I then had to change to this:

```
let result: JsonArray | "error";
```

I have no control over the REST api call as far as what it returns.

This all seems a little kludgy so looking for some advice.

Comment: You can't index into a union unless you know the key is present, so you can use [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) to do that (along with truthiness and object type checking).  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMlOkN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi  @jcalz
Thanks for the response. You aren't missing anything.   
I should have added that in some of my REST call responses, I might get back over 150 plus fields and I might need to access as many as 30 or 40 of them.  I know they will be there. It is just that the other 80+ or more fields , I am not interested in. 
That was partly why I added the interface and defined the 2 example fields - reasonCode and message above.  These being 2 of the fields I need to get at.

Comment: If you know they will be there but the compiler doesn't you can presumably use an interface, but it's very confusing to imagine an `Array<Json>` as also having a `reasonCode` property (In JavaScript you could write `Object.assign([0, 1, 2], {reasonCode: "xyz"})` but there's no way that's going to survive JSON encoding and decoding).  The answer given by noam is vaguely similar to my suggestion above, so I'm not inclined to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive type alias defines a generic JSON structure, with no specific known fields, so TypeScript is correct when telling you that the field `reasonCode` might not exist in a value of this type.

For example, in case `result === "error"` is true (which, based on your description, is a possible situation), then `result` is of type `string` and naturally it has no `reasonCode` field.

If your code would first make sure that the value we're dealing with is indeed not a number, a string, a boolean, a null or an array, then TS would be able to assume that the value is a key-value object corresponding to `{ [key: string]: Json }` which should allow accessing any fields with a string key.

Checking that is a little tricky, because the `typeof` of both arrays and null values is `"object"` as well. It should be something like this:

```js
if (result && !Array.isArray(result) && typeof result === 'object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing a JSON string is typically a point where invalid code *could* enter your code. For example, if that JSON string is retrieved from LocalStorage, it's possible for the user to have modified it directly. Without proper type checking, this can lead to unhandled errors.

There are a few ways of addressing this potential risk, and which one works best is going to vary from case to case.

For example, if you can be very confident that you know what your parsed JSON object will look like, you could consider using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the TypeScript compiler what sort of object was returned by `JSON.parse`. This won't provide you with any type safety - you'll be *asserting* that the type is correct - but it has the advantage of not involving much code and having a very low maintenance cost.

Alternatively, you can cast that type to `unknown` instead of using TypeScript's default behaviour of having it return `any`. With this approach, TypeScript will require you to narrow the type before you use it.

---

*As a brief aside, there is an npm package called [ts-reset](https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset) which modified a few of TypeScript's built-in types, and one of the changes it makes is to have `JSON.parse` return `unknown` for improved type safety.*

---

There are a few ways to manage this sort of type checking. Once again, the best one for your is going to depend on your use case.

The most obvious approach is to write the type check yourself. This can work well with very simple types, but it comes with some risk and maintenance cost. For example:

```js
type Result = 'error' | {
    reasonCode: string;
    message: string;
}

function isResult(value: unknown): value is Result {
    if (value === 'error') {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(
        typeof value === 'object' &&
        value !== null
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(
        'reasonCode' in value &&
        typeof value.reasonCode === 'string'
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(
        'message' in value &&
        typeof value.message === 'string'
    )) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// ...

declare const resultJSON: string;

const result = JSON.parse(resultJSON) as unknown;

if (!isResult(result)) {
    throw new Error('Handle this error somehow');
}

result; // <- Result
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKByCAnXA9rllAD5QDeAUFLVLhAIbwEB2AwgQCYQBcU8YLgCWrAOYBuGnQC2CeIzF8BQ0ZKoBfKlQBmiVgGNgwtlGHw4SVAAoAbo2SJl+gNasCAd1YBKfvcfQ5rAIKGjUdGY6UHYOThjomDj4RFjelNIRtAzAiLisUEJOUhFaGZHRAITWZRGgkARR-nEJiQQARgBWEEYkAGS9NXRN0BUJUKwoyGXeaeGZWRA5eVA6DvAQxXSlEcJR1lWDtFgMzGycPCSiUMNQ-YcF4BAN17EQAHQnLBzc0C3YgiJxFhprN7tlcvlVsh1ptaNs6LtKtV5kc5PAFEpLvkbncUQ96o1Xm80RjfmMsAC1MCIjN0njwcsoTCyvCFkt8oUNpptAB6HlQN6C7Q8AzIRgMKAGNiCeghVAAKQAygB5ABy-Ep4ikVClrBlDCsaEwSrVbzA4vW1gNoRNqrSzCgrncXm1iP25ksoStcuAtLmtGAAAtCB5xhBQwBRZK4axYAASjFYXGQ0CDQTwhFwAgIckDnlSUlK1tQEigfKgAB4ALTBQ1UIA)

As I'm sure you can tell, the complexity of that custom typeguard function will grow quite quickly when using more complex types. It's also possible to make mistakes in the checks that you do, but TypeScript takes your word for it when it comes to the `value is Result` part of your function's type definition.

Another approach you could take to this problem, which works better with more complex types or types that might still be in flux (which can often happen during development) is to use a library that allows you to define a *type schema* that can be used to generate both TypeScript types and a type checking function that can be run in JavaScript.

There are a few well-established libraries available that fill this niche. Personally, I quite like [Zod](https://zod.dev/) but here are a few others:

- [Ajv](https://ajv.js.org/)
- [Joi](https://joi.dev/)
- [myzod](https://github.com/davidmdm/myzod)
- [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)

Here's an example of how you could use Zod:

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

const resultSchema =
    z.literal('error')
    .or(z.object({
        reasonCode: z.string(),
        message: z.string(),
    }));

// ...

declare const resultJSON: string;

const parsedResult = JSON.parse(resultJSON) as unknown;

// Will throw an error if `parsedResult` doesn't match the schema
// Otherwise, returns a deep copy with a well-defined type
const result = resultSchema.parse(parsedResult);

result; // <- 'error' | { reasonCode: string; message: string; }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFAxhAHYDO8UApgwK4A2MAytQBYsQAQzgBeCnCkoAdJ2AwWUYZwAU+JTij4AlJOkzoq5IYBGAKxbUYqhPunTWwhvQDCJFgC5ZTKMDoA5qo6ADT2DnAgbAzCAV4+MH6BwWEOaDo6lBQwAJ5gLHAASmxc8GKy-phKADy5+RCYcKwc3HyCIgB8WQD03XAyA1TEVpzCrHC0jMwl3ABSPADyAHLevv4BWZNMcGBjDCzExS1lcPPLMrtQ+6rNpWdLOnDOcOx0ANZ0EADudD19AOrATicOAwfg4L5POhwTTQODARoAA0u+0OMxgiLgxAgbDo+HgIhgAlBgjgDAEQmEFF6cAWYKUX2A+xCTRYMHYUEYTyxLBYYAmEDAOTgjLB3K+LGBAFphph-AdQXkWDR6NtbtxxKzjm1KRc9ixVCiDkdSpkqOqYGQ4DTqlKiuiKEA)

As you can see, this requires less code than writing a typeguard function yourself, but it also involves using different (and perhaps less familiar) syntax to define your type.

There are different costs and benefits to each of these approaches, so I can't say definitively which is best for you. But I hope I've at least given you some helpful options.